# Find a diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Find a diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$

$SO(3) =$ {${A \in M_3(\mathbb{R}) : A^TA = I, \det(A) = 1}$}, which is the special orthogonal group. And $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is the real projective space.

I am trying to find an atlas for $SO(3)$. In order to do that, I would like to find a diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$. I know how to show that they are diffeomorphic ([e.g.](https://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/courses/difftop.pdf#page=17)), but I am not sure how to find an explicit diffeomorphism.

Comment: You said you know how to show that they're diffeomorphic. How? (I'd show they are both diffeomorphic to the solid ball with antipodal points identified, maybe you can get explicit diffeomorphisms from that? I honestly don't know)

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi To be fair, I should have said that I have found proofs as to why they are diffeomorphic. [Here is one example.](https://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/courses/difftop.pdf#page=17)

Comment: See also www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geombchap8.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $B$ be a closed 3-ball of radius $\pi$. Define the equivalence relation on $\partial B$ by $x\sim y$ if $x=-y$. Then $\mathbb RP^3$ can be considered as the quotient space $B/\sim$.  So any point $[x]\in\mathbb RP^3$ is an equivalence class of a point $x$ in the ball. If $|x|<\pi$, then the equivalence class is $[x]=\{x\}$. If $|x|=\pi$, then $[x]=\{x,-x\}$.

$SO(3)$ is the set of all $3\times 3$ rotation matrices. We can specify a rotation by a direction in $\mathbb R^3$ along with a magnitude in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Of course, the a rotation by $\pi$ is equivalent to a rotation by $-\pi$. Therefore, we can represent any element of $SO(3)$ besides the identity by the ordered pair $(\vec v,m)$ where $\vec v$ is the unit vector in the direction of the rotation, and $m$ is the magnitude (between $-\pi$ and $\pi$). We represent the identity by $I$. The explicit diffeomorphism is $$f(\vec v,m)=[m\vec v],$$ and $$f(I)=0.$$

Now you just need to show that this is in fact a well-defined diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! What would the inverse of this map be? Given $[x] \in \mathbb{R}P^3$ what is $\vec v, m$?

Comment: The inverse is $f^{-1}([x])=(x/\Vert x\Vert,\Vert x\Vert)$. I defined $\vec v$ and $m$ in the answer. Which part of the definition is confusing to you?

Comment: Thanks again! No, I understand. I meant what's $\vec v$ and $m$ in terms of $x$ for the inverse.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood. Also, note my recent edit. I forgot to include the identity.